# Can this be removed? "Index: [], Empty DataFrame" and correctly read in

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently reading in .txt files from a folder into an array, then appending each array to a list.

```
path_M = r'FYP_Datasets/Large_Movie_dataset/aclImdb/train/pos//'
all_files = glob.glob(path_M + "*.txt")

for filename in all_files:
    temp = np.loadtxt(filename,dtype=str,encoding="UTF-8")
    li.append(temp)
print(li)
```

When I print the list, it is printing out `"Index: [], Empty DataFrame"`

Is there a way to remove this?
Ideally, I want the text file read into a list with each word separated. Then that array put into one overall list.
i.e. `[ ["I", "am", "here"] ["You", "Are", "Here"] ]`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `if` condition when printing out the elements of the `li` list to only print out the numpy array that are not empty:

```
for df in li:
    if df.size:
        print(df)
```

To eliminate the empty numpy arrays from the `li` list, you can use a list comprehension:

```
li = [df for df in li if df.size]
```

Or you can avoid appending the empty numpy array to the list in the first place:

```
for filename in all_files:
    df = np.loadtxt(filename,dtype=str,encoding="UTF-8")
    if df.size:
        li.append(df)
```

Comment: Ideally, I will need to manipulate the data in the numpy array at a later time, is there a way to get rid of them entirely?

Comment: @Eoghan1232 Updated.

Comment: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'empty'
I feel my variable name was misleading as I originally had it has a DF, its a numpy array so I now get this error.

Comment: Update: I changed the .empty to .size == 0 and it now worked.
Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @Eoghan1232 that is not necessary, just use `if df.size` :)